# How to remove plot gridlines using Highcharts in R

Tags: r, highcharts

Here is my sample plot

```
require(highcharter)
require(tidyverse)
highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = c(7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2,
                         26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6),
                type = "spline")
```

I want to keep the axis but remove the plot gridlines and hence I'm doing this. I have used this guide as a [reference](http://jsfiddle.net/971yaxd4/1/) :

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = c(7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2,
                         26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6),
                type = "spline") %>% 
  hc_xAxis( tickLength = 0,
   gridLineColor = 'transparent')
```

However, the grid lines are still present. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made **xAxis** gridlines transparent, but you should hide **yAxis** gridlines :)

x -> y